# FCM push notification not showing when app is open in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to show fcm message any time if my app is open or not open.I want to catch message and save core data.when my app is opened I will get my message but notification alert doesn't show. But when I close my app it shows my message but I did not get my message in background.. here is my appDelegate

```
   @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,MessagingDelegate{

   var window: UIWindow?


     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()

      return true
}

//MARK: FCM Token Refreshed
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    // FCM token updated, update it on Backend Server
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Messaging",messaging)
    print("remoteMessage*******************",remoteMessage)
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from foreground")
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")


    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active { // In iOS 10 if app is in foreground do nothing.
        print("active****")
        completionHandler([])
    } else { // If app is not active you can show banner, sound and badge.
        print("Not active****")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from background or closed")
    print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

}



func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    //  print("fcm**************************","Dhruw: Connected to FCM. Token : \(String(describing: refreshedToken))")
    var fcm_token = String(describing: refreshedToken!)


    print("fcm toker********",fcm_token);


    connectToFCM()
}

func connectToFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}



func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Finjo_Expense_Management")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    guard let messageId = userInfo["gcm.message_id"]
        else {

            return
    }

    print(messageId)

    print("did*****",userInfo);

    let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary
    var message = aps?["alert"] as! String;
    print("message",message)

}

// Called when APNs has assigned the device a unique token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    // Print it to console
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
    //09256B251D3BBEAA50949067DF40AB75E5D2668170AB0C3B0D310205F2876C32

    // Persist it in your backend in case it's new
}

// Called when APNs failed to register the device for push notifications
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
    print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
}


func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
       }
   }

  }
```

With Advance thanks...Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322495/1825618

Answer (score 1):

When app is open you need to set localnotification for showing notifications.. otherwise you need to show custom view.